# Android Studio- Unable to navigate in emulator

Tags: android, navigation, android-studio, emulation

For some reason, when I run an Android Virtual Device in Android Studio, I see no back button.
I also tried to use my computer's keyboard, but could not find the key configurations to do that.
Can anyone please point out, where I am going wrong..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `escape` key on your keyboard is the equivalent of a hardware back button.

Yes, its not well documented.